# Как забрать цифровые значения, а не текст

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 активити, в первом вводятся цифровые значения

```
switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_sum:
                // Говорим между какими Activity будет происходить связь
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsnActivityOutput.class);

                // указываем первым параметром ключ, а второе значение
                // по ключу мы будем получать значение с Intent
                intent.putExtra("inputQuarter1", inputQuarter1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("inputQuarter2", inputQuarter2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("inputQuarter3", inputQuarter3.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("inputQuarter4", inputQuarter4.getText().toString());

                // показываем новое Activity
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

оно перенаправляет нас на другое активити

```
outTax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outTax);
    outQuarter1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outInsure);
    outQuarter2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outInsure);
    outQuarter3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outInsure);
    outQuarter4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outInsure);


    String txtQuarter1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("inputQuarter1");
    String txtQuarter2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("inputQuarter2");
    String txtQuarter3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("inputQuarter3");
    String txtQuarter4 = getIntent().getStringExtra("inputQuarter4");



    outTax.setText(outTax.getText().toString() + " " + txtQuarter1 + txtQuarter2 + txtQuarter3 + txtQuarter4);
```

в данном случае цифры выводятся как текст по порядку, как сделать так что бы забирались именно цифры, для последующего сложения, пробовал делать через Parse, в цифры преобразовывает, но все так же выводит их по порядку, а не складывает между собой, помогите решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Происходит это потому что при установке текста "+" имеет не математическое применение, а используется для сложения текста. Все переменные у вас просто превращаются в текст. Поэтому вам нужно сначала сложить их все, а уже потом закидывать в текст

```
final Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
String txtQuarter1 = arguments.getString("inputQuarter1");
String txtQuarter2 = arguments.getString("inputQuarter2");
String txtQuarter3 = arguments.getString("inputQuarter3");
String txtQuarter4 = arguments.getString("inputQuarter4");

int Quarter1 = Integer.parseInt(txtQuarter1);
int Quarter2 = Integer.parseInt(txtQuarter2);
int Quarter3 = Integer.parseInt(txtQuarter3);
int Quarter4 = Integer.parseInt(txtQuarter4);

int result = Quarter1 + Quarter2 + Quarter3 + Quarter4;

outTax.setText(outTax.getText().toString() + " " + String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!